# How can I optimize this function to find statistical mode in vector-like container with billions of elements

Tags: c++, optimization, statistics, hashset, unordered-set

I have a very slow and hefty function to find statistical mode (including multiple modes) which is working but unusably slow.

The requirements are as follows.

1. Must take an std::vector-like container by reference
2. Returns an std::vector of std::pair with the 'first' being the statistical mode and the 'second' being the number of occurrences (the number of occurrences must be identical for every statistical mode found or there is a bug (not currently verifying this)
3. Must be able to find all statistical modes in a container

**4. Must be able to operate on containers billions of elements long and run in a reasonable amount of time**

That last one is the one I'm having trouble with. Currently my code takes about 7 seconds to run on std::vectors containing only **1,000,000** elements.

Thus computing the mode(s) for a container of 1 billion elements would take about 2.38 hours. Ideally this code would run in under 1 minute.

How can I optimize this, I know std::unordered set is kind of expensive but I don't know how to implement this function without a set-like container using an array or vector.

```
 template<typename CONTAINER_T, typename T = CONTAINER_T::value_type>
    [[nodiscard]] inline constexpr std::vector<std::pair<T, size_t>> mode(CONTAINER_T& arr)
    {   
        std::unordered_set<T> seen;

        size_t max_count = 0;
        std::vector<std::pair<T, size_t>> ret;

        for (auto i = arr.begin(); i != arr.end(); ++i)
        {
            if (*std::find(std::execution::par_unseq, seen.cbegin(), seen.cend(), *i) == *seen.cend())
            {
                const size_t count = std::count(std::execution::par_unseq, i, arr.end(), *i);

                if (count > max_count)
                {
                    max_count = count;
                    ret = { {*i, max_count} };
                }//End if
                else if (count == max_count)
                {
                    ret.emplace_back(*i, max_count);
                }//End if
                seen.insert(*i);
            }//End if
        }//End for

        return ret;
    }//End of mode
```

Comment: If you have already working code, you want to get improved, better ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem is not `unordered_set` (though you are using it wrong), it's the fact that your algorithm is quadratic. Just doing two passes - one to populate `std::unordered_map<T, int>` with counts and compute `max_count`, and the second pass over the map to extract elements that occur `max_count` times - would be much faster, I expect.

Comment: `find` in an unordered_set? That completely defeats the purpose...

Comment: *billions of elements* -- Sounds like what you need is a running total or similar, not one container holding billions of elements.  If those elements do not need to be retained, but each one used in some way as you get them, then more than likely using a container of a billion elements is not a viable solution.

Comment: What's your definition of a "reasonable" amount of time?   Clearly, you consider seven seconds for a million elements doesn't qualify.    What does?

Comment: Firstly, profile.  Find out where in your code most of the time is spent.  Secondly, remove the requirement or optimize the design.  Lastly, use a more efficient implementation.

Comment: I'm just impressed that you can get a std::vector with billions of elements, that's quite a feat.

Comment: `*seen.cend()` is going to cause *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
template<typename CONTAINER_T, typename T = CONTAINER_T::value_type>
std::vector<std::pair<T, size_t>> mode(CONTAINER_T& arr) {   
  size_t max_count = 0;
  std::unodered_map<T, size_t> counts;
  for (auto& elem : arr) {
    size_t count = ++counts[elem];
    max_count = std::max(max_count, count);
  }
  std::vector<std::pair<T, size_t>> result;
  for (auto& pair : counts) {
    if (pair.second == max_count) {
      result.push_back(pair);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```